# Can anyone tell me what this circuit is doing?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, inductor, frequency

[image]

I am reluctant to share the whole circuit due to company confidentiality, but effectively a frequency ref is inputted into Q1B. Q1a's collector is connected to 3V3 through a series of resistors and a frequency output can be measured there based on manipulating a capacitor connected to the collector of Q1B

What is the deal with the two NPN transistors Q1A and Q1B? I assume it is something to do with charging / discharging the inductor L3?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: In the absence of more of the circuit, or at least an explanation of the overall system function, I suspect you question will be closed as lacking clarity/detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right you have an oscillator that generates a square wave or a periodic pulse train. See the 2 BJT transistors and the COG capacitors.

That circuit on the right makes me think to an ultra low power oscillator designed by David Johnson at discoverycircuits.com

The whole circuit might be a mixer between Q1 reference frequency and the signal generated by the oscillator on the right.